# Formik state is resetting field values unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form and song state where I am trying to attach a new field "appleMusicId", however whenever I do this, it resets the timeDescription and sceneDescription values.

I've been trying to fix for hours and am worried I'm overlooking something simple.

As an example when I first hit Submit I get this for the console.log values

```
{
    "episodeId": 5,
    "spotifyId": "3NanY0K4okhIQzL33U5Ad8",
    "name": "Boy's a liar",
    "artistName": "PinkPantheress",
    "timeDescription": 12,
    "sceneDescription": "First song at the party."
}
```

If I then click the "Add Apple ID" button, the values become this on onSubmit and the time and scene removed.

```
{
    "episodeId": 5,
    "spotifyId": "3NanY0K4okhIQzL33U5Ad8",
    "name": "Boy's a liar",
    "artistName": "PinkPantheress",
    "appleMusicId": "dummyId"
}
```

Component

```
import { TextField } from "@/components/TextField";
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { validate } from "graphql";
import { useState } from "react";

const initialValues = {
    name: "",
    artistName: "",
    episodeId: undefined,
    movieId: undefined,
    spotifyId: "",
    appleMusicId: "",
    sceneDescription: "",
    timeDescription: undefined,
  };

const AddSong = () => {
    const [song, setSong] = useState(initialValues);

    const submit = (values: any) => {
        console.log(values, "values");
    }

    const addAppleId = () => {
        setSong((v) => {
          return {
            ...v,
            appleMusicId: "dummyId",
          };
        });
      };

    return (
        <Formik
        initialValues={song}
        onSubmit={(values) => submit(values)}
        validationSchema={validate}
        enableReinitialize={true}
      >
        <Form>
          <TextField name={"name"} label={"Name"} type="text" />
          <TextField name={"artistName"} label={"Artist Name"} type="text" />
          <TextField
            name={"timeDescription"}
            label={"Time Description"}
            type="number"
            placeholder="How many minutes in, was this song played?"
          />
          <TextField
            name={"sceneDescription"}
            label={"Scene Description"}
            type="text"
          />
            <Button onClick={addAppleId}>Test Add Apple Id</Button>
          <Button isLoading={isLoading} type={"submit"}>
            Create
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    )
};
```

TextField (if you need to see it)

```
export const TextField = ({ label, value, ...props }: TextFieldProps) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <FormControl
      isInvalid={
        meta.touched && (meta.error && meta.error?.length > 0 ? true : false)
      }
      mb={3}
    >
      <FormLabel
        aria-label={field.name}
        htmlFor={field.name}
        mb={0}
        textColor={useColorModeValue('gray.700', 'gray.100')}
      >
        {label}
      </FormLabel>
      <Input
        {...field}
        {...props}
        value={value ? value : undefined}
        autoComplete="off"
        borderRadius={0}
        paddingLeft={2}
        border={"2px solid"}
        borderColor={"gray.200"}
        _invalid={{ borderColor: "error-red" }}
      />
      <ErrorMessage
        name={field.name}
        component="span"
        className="text-sm pt-2 text-red-error"
      />
      <Text pt={1} fontSize={'sm'} color={useColorModeValue('gray.400', 'gray.600')}>{props.footerText}</Text>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bro I have send you proposal on UW Plathform . Please accept it will reolve issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also It would be grat if you check out my proposal.

Best
Asadbek Savronov!

It seems like the issue is happening because you are updating the song state outside of the Formik component and therefore the form values are not updating.

To fix the issue, you need to update the form values within the Formik component. You can do this by passing the setFieldValue prop to your "Add Apple ID" button and updating the form values directly within the Formik component.

Possible Solution:

```
const AddSong = () => {
return (
<Formik
initialValues={initialValues}
onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
validationSchema={validate}
enableReinitialize={true}
>
{({ setFieldValue }) => (
<Form>
<TextField name={"name"} label={"Name"} type="text" />
<TextField name={"artistName"} label={"Artist Name"} type="text" />
<TextField
name={"timeDescription"}
label={"Time Description"}
type="number"
placeholder="How many minutes in, was this song played?"
/>
<TextField
name={"sceneDescription"}
label={"Scene Description"}
type="text"
/>
<Button onClick={() => setFieldValue("appleMusicId", "dummyId")}>
Test Add Apple Id
</Button>
<Button isLoading={isLoading} type={"submit"}>
Create
</Button>
</Form>
)}
</Formik>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

no issue in your code.
I have tried to create my project and run it.

```
import { Formik, Form, useField, ErrorMessage,  } from "formik";
// import { validate } from "graphql";
import { useState } from "react";
import {FormControl, FormLabel, Input} from '@material-ui/core'
import {useColorModeValue, Button, Text} from '@chakra-ui/react'

const TextField = ({ label, value, ...props }) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField(props);
    return (
      <FormControl
        isInvalid={
          meta.touched && (meta.error && meta.error?.length > 0 ? true : false)
        }
        mb={3}
      >
        <FormLabel
          aria-label={field.name}
          htmlFor={field.name}
          mb={0}
          textColor={useColorModeValue('gray.700', 'gray.100')}
        >
          {label}
        </FormLabel>
        <Input
          {...field}
          {...props}
          value={value ? value : undefined}
          autoComplete="off"
          borderRadius={0}
          paddingLeft={2}
          border={"2px solid"}
          borderColor={"gray.200"}
          _invalid={{ borderColor: "error-red" }}
        />
        <ErrorMessage
          name={field.name}
          component="span"
          className="text-sm pt-2 text-red-error"
        />
        <Text pt={1} fontSize={'sm'} color={useColorModeValue('gray.400', 'gray.600')}>{props.footerText}</Text>
      </FormControl>
    );
  };
const initialValues = {
    name: "111111111",
    artistName: "11111111",
    appleMusicId: "",
    sceneDescription: "12",
    timeDescription: 1,
  };



export const AddSong = () => {
    const [song, setSong] = useState(initialValues);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    const submit = (values) => {
        console.log(values, "values");
    }

    const addAppleId = () => {
        setSong((v) => {
          return {
            ...v,
            appleMusicId: "dummyId",
          };
        });
      };

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={song}
            onSubmit={(values) => submit(values)}
            // validationSchema={validate}
            enableReinitialize={true}
        >
        <Form>
          <TextField name={"name"} label={"Name"} type="text" />
          <TextField name={"artistName"} label={"Artist Name"} type="text" />
          <TextField
            name={"timeDescription"}
            label={"Time Description"}
            type="number"
            placeholder="How many minutes in, was this song played?"
          />
          <TextField
            name={"sceneDescription"}
            label={"Scene Description"}
            type="text"
          />
            <Button onClick={addAppleId}>Test Add Apple Id</Button>
            <Button type={"submit"}>
                Create
            </Button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    )
};
```

I am getting log like this:

> {name: '111111111', artistName: '11111111', *appleMusicId: ''*, sceneDescription: '12', timeDescription: 1}

and after adding dummy apple id:

> {name: '111111111', artistName: '11111111', *appleMusicId: 'dummyId'*, sceneDescription: '12', timeDescription: 1}